# Find keys for maximum values in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, max

My routine calculates the wind load on a vertical column with rectangular cross section at all 360 degree compass angles.  As expected, this produces a 360 value array with two exactly the same maximum load values, each opposite the widest face.

Using the following line only identifies one of these angles (array keys).

```php
$wind_angle_at_maximum_force = array_keys($wind_force, max($wind_force));
```

It produces a one value array.

Can this be explained?

Comment: I suggest you add more relevant code to your question.

Comment: Is one of the values negative and one positive?

Comment: Both final numbers are positive, but the numbers are derived from separate vector components. i.e. pow((pow($a, 2) + pow($b, 2)), 0.5) and these components ($a & $b) can be both negative and positive.